# Visual WebPart using Visual Studio 2010 and use XSLT for customize look and feel

Tags: 2010, web-part, sharepoint-designer

I just configured User Profile Synchronization Service on my portal and now need to implement "Employee Directory". I have created a VisualWebPart Solution in Visual Studio 2010 and Programatically iterated through UserProfileManager object and read properties into DATA TAble object.

What I want is to come up with a display like Separate Business Card with the information of each profile like in OUTLOOK contacts card view.

How can I do it please guide.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look here http://techdhaan.wordpress.com/2008/06/03/moss-2007-employee-directory-web-part-using-search-and-data-view-web-parts/